# NSTimer is not firing

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, nstimer

I had everything working fine also the timers where running. But when i ran into weird problems i had to restructure my cocos2d scene. 
Now i am not able to fire the NSTimers anymore, the BonusTimetimer below is not even fired once.

Thanks in advance, below is the code.

```
BonusTimeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(CountTimeBonus:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
// (lately i added the line below, but it does not help)
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:BonusTimeTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


-(void)CountTimeBonus:(NSTimer *) sender {
    NSLog (@"Method -> Countimebonus");
    if ( (scoreTotal + 37) < TargetScore){
        scoreTotal = scoreTotal + 37;
        TimeBonus = TimeBonus-37;
        NSString *level_timebonus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", TimeBonus];
        [labelTimeBonus setString: level_timebonus];
        NSString *scorestr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", scoreTotal];
        [labelMainScore setString: scorestr];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"light_switch_.mp3"];
    }
    else {
        // add the Last few points and finish BonusTimer
        scoreTotal = scoreTotal + TimeBonus;
        TimeBonus=0;
        NSString *level_timebonus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", timebonusgrayed];
        [labelTimeBonus setString: @"" ];
        [labelTimeBonusGrayed setString: level_timebonus];
        NSString *scorestr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", scoreTotal];
        [labelMainScore setString: scorestr];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"light_switch_.mp3"] ;
        [BonusTimeTimer invalidate];
        BonusTimeTimer = nil;
        timeBonusisdone = true;
        timeBonusisactive = false;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I've never really drilled down that rabbit hole (ie why this is), but there is a persistent rumour around here that NSTimer and cocos2d do not mix well. Instead, I use cocos' own methods

```
[self schedule:@selector(CountTimeBonus:) interval:.01];

// and to invalidate this


[self unschedule:@selector(CountTimeBonus:)];
```

the CountTimeBonus signature will be :

```
-(void) CountTimeBonus:(ccTime) dt {
}
```

Comment: Cocos2d's timers also work as you'd expect if the game is paused, for example (ie. they pause firing). Using cocos2d's timers is good advice.

Comment: Thanks that worked,for me. 
And here's a few more things to consdider, 
1) the code:
    [self schedule:@selector(CountTimeBonus:) delay:.01];
hase a syntax problem, use this instead (below):
   [self schedule:@selector(CountTimeBonus:) interval:.01];
2)

Comment: thks, i updated the answer so that others wont have to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks YvesLeBorg that worked for me.

There are a few more things to consider,

1) the cocos2d code:

```
[self schedule:@selector(myTimer:) delay:.01];
```

has a syntax problem, i used this instead (below):

```
[self schedule:@selector(myTimer:) interval:.01];
```

2) I got the NSTimer working again, but when i place the NStimer call in a do-while loop it won't work.

Thanks again and best of luck

Johan